# VIew wireless networks through usb0?

Tags: usb, tethering

this is my first post in these forums and I'm somewhat of a noob to linux, so forgive me if my question seems ludicrous.  I have ubuntu 14.04 and I'm in need of a new wireless card for my compaq laptop, so I'm using my android as a connection to the internet through the interface usb0.  My android is recieving its internet connection via wifi and I was wondering if there was a way to view the available wifi networks in my laptop through my androids wireless interface?